# C - Memory Leak, function return Char*

Tags: c, memory-leaks, char, malloc, free

Doing a refresh on C programming, and I'm having an issue with freeing memory. The below program gives me the below compiler warnings that I'm having a hard time solving for. Valgrind is also informing that there is a memory leak, but I am using free on the memory allocated with malloc(). Any guidance on what I am doing wrong when attempting to free memory on pointer 'alpha' in main() is appreciated?

**Compiler Warning**

```
In function ‘main’:/alphabetArrayPractice/src/main.c:37:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘free’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   37 |     free(*alpha);
      |          ^~~~~~
      |          |
      |          char
In file included from /alphabetArrayPractice/src/main.c:2:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:565:25: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
  565 | extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
```

**Valgrind Report**

```
==950908== 
==950908== HEAP SUMMARY:
==950908==     in use at exit: 27 bytes in 1 blocks
==950908==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,051 bytes allocated
==950908== 
==950908== 27 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==950908==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==950908==    by 0x10919E: get_alphabet_array (main.c:5)
==950908==    by 0x109230: main (main.c:23)
==950908== 
==950908== LEAK SUMMARY:
==950908==    definitely lost: 27 bytes in 1 blocks
==950908==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==950908==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==950908==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==950908==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==950908== 
==950908== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==950908== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* get_alphabet_array(){
    char *alpha =   (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 27);

    for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            alpha[i] = 'A';
        } else if (i < 26) {
                 alpha[i] =  alpha[i-1] + 1;
        } else if (i == 26) {
            alpha[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
       //  printf("Character at index %d is: %c\n", i, alpha[i]);
    }
    return alpha;
}

int main () {

    char* alpha = get_alphabet_array();

    while(*alpha != '\0') {
        static int count = 0;
        printf("Letter at index %d: %c\n", count, *alpha);
        count++;
        *alpha++;
    }

    free(*alpha);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `free(alpha)`, not `free(*alpha)`. `alpha` is the pointer. `*alpha` is what it points to. `free` needs the address (the pointer).

Comment: Using free(alpha) resolves the compiler warnings, but at runtime the program completes as expected with exception to the following, "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)". Valgrind then complains saying I have 2 errors in 2 context. Thank you for the response!

Comment: You need to free the *original* pointer you allocated. Your loop increments the pointer *alpha*, so even though you have `free(alpha)` you're freeing the wrong pointer since the value of `alpha` itself has changed. Save the original pointer and free that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started with this

```
char* alpha = get_alphabet_array();

while(*alpha != '\0') {
    static int count = 0;
    printf("Letter at index %d: %c\n", count, *alpha);
    count++;
    *alpha++;
}

free(*alpha);    // <-- this attempts to free what `alpha` points to (not good)
```

Which, via `free(*alpha)`, attempts to free what `alpha` points to rather than the pointer `alpha`. This or course, does not make sense. So you changed it to this:

```
char* alpha = get_alphabet_array();

while(*alpha != '\0') {
    static int count = 0;
    printf("Letter at index %d: %c\n", count, *alpha);
    count++;
    *alpha++;   // <-- this alters the value of the pointer, `alpha`
}

free(alpha);    // <-- this frees the *altered* value of `alpha` (not good)
```

Now you have a different problem in that the value of `alpha` has changed since you received it from the memory allocation, and `free(alpha)` is freeing the wrong pointer value. You need to free the original pointer. For example,

```
char* alpha = get_alphabet_array();

for (char *p = alpha; *p != '\0'; p++) {   // this loop does not alter `alpha`
    static int count = 0;
    printf("Letter at index %d: %c\n", count, *p);
    count++;
}

free(alpha);    // <-- this frees the originally allocated pointer
```

As an aside, the statement `*alpha++;` increments the pointer in `alpha`, then dereferences the pointer and discards the result. So the `*` here doesn't really serve any purpose or function.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm unable to mark this as the solution due to low reputation score, but greatly appreciate the response.

Comment: @NullPointer glad it helped! I believe you can "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark, even though you cannot upvote it.